# How to upgrade Spring in a Continuous Deployment environment

Tags: java, spring, continuous-deployment

We're starting a pilot to do continuous deployment (though with dark code behind feature flags for now), for a 15+ year old monolithic application with less than ideal automated test coverage. We've read enough/played enough to understand how to do it in steps, addressing our automated debt as we go.

But one big question came up: how do we upgrade Spring Framework in a continuous model without doing a big bang? Experience has told us even minor spring releases (3.1 to 3.2 for example) had some regression we had to thoroughly test, including a fair amount of manual testing.

Since we can't 'dark' release a Spring upgrade is a feature branch our only option to figure out everything codewise that changed and execute our regression suite?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid it.  All or none.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Spring is mostly backwards compatible (over the last 10 years I have done several Spring upgrades), unless you have broken some invariant or overridden framework methods, like DispatcherServlet.doDispatch (Which I had to do once).

If you have low test coverage, my personal recommendation is to convince you manager that you need more tests before you do deploy anything else. In my personel opinion is that you can't run a continuous delivery/deployment with less than 50% coverage, and you need to check all the critical paths of the system.

Where I work we are quite lucky because the code is fairly new, so we have roughly 65% (line) coverage in unit tests, and after we deploy to staging we run a number of integration test that checks all third party integrations and well as critical features in our own app (Signup, login, reset password, etc.), before code is deployed to production - We would have no scrupulous about upgrading any library, typically we would only do it when needed or if the library is more then 2 years old. We often deploy to production more than once a day, and we operate financial software with transactions of several million dollars a day - We have one tester which typically only test after production deployment!